# Spring way to copy Entity Bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I try to solve https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-373 . For this I need to copy the "old" entity, so that I have a "snapshot" before Spring Data Rest and Jackson modify the entity to a "new" entity.

**I found two ways to do that:**

- Detach entity from transaction, but then I have two `findOne` database requests and thats not nice. (edit: no option, because lazy initialization)
- Copy bean with `BeanUtils.copyProperties`, but then e.g. the private field `id` wouldn't be copied

However, is there a Spring way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no "Spring way" to do this.

If BeanUtils isn't enough for your purpose you might want to look into [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html), [which does support copying private fields according to this FAQ entry](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html#dataobject-support).

Comment: But I think if I'm using external tools, the SDR-Team would accept an Pull-Request.

Comment: Sorry, thought you just wanted to fix it for your problem at hand. You are right, PRs with external dependencies have almost no chance of acceptance. But I actually don't see a good solution at all for this issue. Let's discuss this on the issue.